# Max and min PHP function from SQL result

Tags: php, sql, arrays, max, min

I'm quite new in PHP dev and I can't find a way to solve my problem.
I have to clean a some data in my Mysql database. I have a `date` column in my DB full of time periods like

```
-520;-510;0;-500;-530;-599;-499;-510;-490;-500;0;-450
```

and I want to extract the min and max value from it, so that I will only have 2 time period left.

I tried this :

```
$sql = "SELECT date FROM records WHERE serial = 1";
$requete = mysql_query($sql,$cnx) or die(".mysql_error().");
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($requete))
{
    $res = $result[date];
    $min = min($res);
    $max = max($res);
}
```

I understand that it can't work because min and max functions are only working with an array but I don't know how to tranform my `$result[date]` in an new array.

Comment: PHP's `ext/mysql` (the `mysql_*` family) is [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated).  Please use [something else](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that the DB "date" field contains a string of numbers seperated by ; like you described then you can use the explode() function to turn that string into an array and then use max() and min() on that array

```
$arr = explode(";",$string);
$max = max($arr);
$min = min($arr);
```

if it s a one number per row then do it with SQL like described in the other answer

Comment: You'r right my field "date" contains a string of numbers separated by ";". I tried this :                                       while($result = mysql_fetch_array($requete))
{
 $res = $result[date];
 $arr = explode(";",$res);
 $max = max($arr);
 $min = min($arr);
}                                                                 There is not php function error anymore but it returns my string without ";", no change, no max or min value isolated.

Comment: instead of using mysql_fetch_array try using mysql_fetch_assoc, also make sure to put the field name in qoutes like $arr["date"] otherwise it will try looking for a contstant named date (you can use date with no qoutes but it makes php "look" for the date field instead of just getting there)

Comment: I'm trying to vote up but it doesn't work. thank's anynay for you help. It was really usefull

Answer (score 5):

Do this in SQL, something like this should work:

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX( date) as maximum, MIN( date) as minimum
            FROM records 
        WHERE serial = 1
        GROUP BY serial";
```

Then to retrieve the result, you need one row:

```
$requete = mysql_query($sql,$cnx) or die( mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($requete);
echo $row['maximum'] . ' ' . $row['minimum'];
```